# Duplicate Component id in icefaces 1.8.2

Tags: icefaces-1.8

showall_Bean gives me whole list in datatable....

here..i have put edit button....but and it goes to update page......but when i do changes and click on update button it shows error " Duplicate component Id "
 but updates are done in DAtabase...

```
<ice:dataTable value="#{showall_Bean.list}" var="list" border="2" width="100%"
                id="dat`enter code here`atable123" rows="7" binding="#{showall_Bean.dataTable}"
                bgcolor="Silver" resizable="true">
                <ice:column id="c1">
                    <f:facet name="header" >
                        <ice:outputText id ="roll_text" value="Roll"></ice:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ice:outputText id ="roll_text1" value="#{list.roll}"></ice:outputText>
                </ice:column>
                <ice:column id="c2">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <ice:outputText id ="name_text" value="Name"></ice:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ice:outputText value="#{list.name}"></ice:outputText>
                </ice:column>
                <ice:column id="c3">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <ice:outputText id ="sex_text" value="Sex"></ice:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ice:outputText value="#{list.sex}"></ice:outputText>
                </ice:column>
                <ice:column id="c4">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <ice:outputText id ="address_text" value="Address"></ice:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ice:outputText value="#{list.address}"></ice:outputText>
                </ice:column>
                <ice:column id="c5">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <ice:outputText id ="city_text" value="City"></ice:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ice:outputText value="#{list.city}"></ice:outputText>
                </ice:column>
                <ice:column id="c6">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <ice:outputText id ="state_text" value="State"></ice:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ice:outputText  value="#{list.state}"></ice:outputText>
                </ice:column>
                <ice:column id="c7">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <ice:outputText id ="dob_text" value="DOB"></ice:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ice:outputText value="#{list.dob}"></ice:outputText>
                </ice:column>
                <ice:column id="c8">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <ice:outputText id ="field_text" value="Field"></ice:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ice:outputText value="#{list.field}"></ice:outputText>
                </ice:column>
                <ice:column id="c9">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <ice:outputText id ="action_text" value="Action"></ice:outputText>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ice:commandButton value="Edit" id="update" action="#{showall_Bean.Savedata}"></ice:commandButton>
                    <ice:commandButton value="Delete" id="delete"
                        action="#{showall_Bean.Delete_data}"></ice:commandButton>
                </ice:column>
            </ice:dataTable>
<ice:commandButton value="ADD" id="add" action="#{add_Bean.initCreate}"></ice:commandButton>
```